# Some problems in Number theory

Tags: number-theory

1.What should be added to $15^{81}$ to make it divisible by 7 ? Suggest a general technique to counter problems like this.

2.For how many two-digit numbers, the sum of the digits is greater than the product of the digits?

Comment: How about 7 - 15^{81}?

Comment: Hmm not getting what you meant ??

Comment: I mean that 15^{81} + (7 - 15^{81}) is divisible by 7.

Comment: Wow, that's intuitive but unfortunately that's not the solution set :)

Comment: If any of the answers you get help you, you could accept them by clicking the ghostly check mark beside them.

Answer (score 2):

For the second question, for single digits $a+b\geq ab$ when a=0 or 1, b=0 or 1, or a=b=2.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to these is to reduce your base number according to the modulus. So since $15\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, you would have $15^{89}\equiv 1^{89}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. In other words, $15^{89}$ is 1 greater than a multiple of $7$, or 6 less than a multiple of $7$. So to get a complete solution set, you could add any integer of the form $6+7k$, or $-1+7k$, and these two sets coincide. So you can take either what must be subtracted or added to get the number to a multiple of your modulus. For example, for $29^2=841$, you could either add 4 to get 845, or subtract 1 to get 840, both of which are divisible by 5.

For the second, as was noted in the comments, $29^2\equiv(-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, and you should be able to get a complete solution set by the same reasoning. I just mentioned $29\equiv -1$ since $(-1)^2$ is nicer to deal with than $4^2$, and you would have to reduce 16 modulo 5 anyway.

Comment: A good approach is to note that the order of a subgroup is a divisor of the order of the group.

Comment: I am just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** For the first one use the fact that $15^{2} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 7)$

Comment: Is it really $15^{2} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 7)$ ? or you meant $15 \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 7)$ ?

Comment: However the results is same.

Comment: Okay I can see it's 6,but may be I am not getting the correct way to .. since what abt "What will be added to $29^2$ so that it will be a divided by 5 , here $29 \equiv 4 \text{ mod 5 }$ , How to get the result here ?

Comment: @Trewick Marian: Correct

Comment: In short I am getting ... what should be subtracted to get it divisible but not what should be added.

Comment: @Trewick Marian It may be useful to note that $29\equiv -1\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Umm so I am right I am not getting the correct way, would anybody care to explain the approach ?